# Determine whether or not the set of real numbers $\mathbb R$, together with the operation* defined by $a ∗ b = (a+b)/3$, forms a group.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

How would one show this is associative? I think I've shown it is closed but I'm not sure how to show it is associative.

Comment: Just check if $a*(b*c) = (a*b)*c$

Answer (score 3):

$a*(b*c) = a*\left[\dfrac{b+c}{3}\right] = \dfrac{a+\dfrac{b+c}{3}}{3} = \dfrac{3a+b+c}{9}$

and

$(a*b)*c = \left[\dfrac{a+b}{3}\right]*c = \dfrac{\dfrac{a+b}{3}+c}{3} = \dfrac{a+b+3c}{9}$

So the operation is not associative. Take $a=b=0$, $c=1$ for  quick counter example.

Comment: There is also no identity element for this operation in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

The only associative linear functions  $\,a*b = ja+kb\,$ are the trivial ones: $\,0,\,\ a,\,\ b,\,\ a+b.$

$$\begin{eqnarray}a*(b*c) &=& a*(jb+kc) =\ j\,a+jkb+k^2c\\ 
(a*b)*c &=& (ja+kb)*c = j^2a+jkb+k\,c\end{eqnarray}$$

which are equal iff $\,(j^2-j)a = (k^2\!-k) c,\ $ so $\ j,k\in \{0,1\}$ by $\ a,c=1,0\,$ or $\,0,1.$

Answer (score 0):

For Associativity;

$(a*b)*c=\frac{(a+b)}{3}*c=\frac{(\frac{(a+b)}{3}+c)}{3}\neq\frac{a+\frac{(b+c)}{3})}{3}=a*\frac{(b+c)}{3}=a*(b*c)$. $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$

Hence not a group

Comment: This was already posted. And you need to clarify what $\ne$ means here.

Comment: Yes, didn't see that until I posted mine. Since we were considering the set of real numbers i don't thinkt there is any confusion on interpreting $\neq$, is it?

Comment: Yes, there is (there are implicit quantifiers in the statement).

Comment: Ah, of course! Editing right away, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Now what you wrote is false.

Comment: If $a,b,c = 0$ the $\ne$ is false.

Comment: Now you need to clarify again what you mean, we are back at the beginning.